# Saving textbox value from a test execution in Ranorex

Tags: sharepoint, textbox, export-to-excel, export-to-csv, ranorex

I am automating Sharepoint list testing, filling up some field with values,
and like to save data I supplied to the field after.

Is there a way to automate saving the field value in a excel or csv?

Comment: Can you clarify the source of the field data values?  Because, the answer to your question is quite simple.  Since Ranorex is based on the .NET framework, it is really easy to output anything to any type of output.  But if your data is already coming from an excel file (using an excel data connector on your test suite) or a csv file, I do not see the point of writing it to another file...

Comment: The data will come from the share point box. 
For example i have some text box in a list entry in a share point site namely FirstName and LastName on execution of the ranorex i want the content of the two field to be save in a file an excel or csv and be use by other process is that possible.

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep it simple, I would create two recordings and write to a text file (csv).

The first one would get the text values from the desired fields and return them in bound variables using Ranorex **GetValue** action.

The second recording would write the content of the bound variables to a text file, separating fields with ',' (or any other character that is suitable for the kind of data that is present in the fields) in a user code function.

If you have no idea how to write to a file in .NET, take a look at **System.IO.File.AppendAllLines** or similar functions.

You could also combine the 2 recordings in one, but then, re-useability would be limited the scope of the SharePoint page you are testing.

Do not forget that since Ranorex is using the .NET framework, you have access to all the functions provided by the framework in user code.  With Ranorex, the usual question is not ask if something is possible. The real question is "how can it be done" and is the solution simple enough for testers to be able to use it!

Hope this helps!